# Magento2 : Free shipping and Flat Rate for specified states

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping

How the customers who place orders to be shipped within the 48 contiguous states we should show a text stating

> Shipping is free if you need shipping to any one of the 48 contiguous
>   states. Your order will get delivered in 2 to 3 Business Days.
>   Shipping to Alaska and Hawaii are Chargeable at $2 Per item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to main menu > Marketing > **Catalog price rule**

Create Cart price rule to offer free Shipping and

In conditions select the state/provinces in which you want to offer free shipping

In Actions select free shipping to be **yes.**

Comment: Not working. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Log in to Magento Admin, MARKETING > Cart Price Rules and create cart price rules.

Before that, please give some higher number for minimum order amount in configuration -> free shipping.

[image]

Then follow the things in the below screenshot.

[image]

Then it will work sure.